# Stringing together multiples of the same string (an asterisk) determined by an input file. C++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Essentially, the objective is to read an input file (hence `inFile` and `inFileName`) and output a population growth with asterisks representing each 1000 people using an ID (ex. 1375892), going from the year 1900 to 2020 in 20-year increments.

So, 1 asterisk for 1000 people, 3 asterisks for 3000 people, etc. The input file has numbers like 5000 and 7000 that I need to use to calculate the number of asterisks I need (by dividing by 1000). Even with that, I'm trying to figure out the final step in converting `asteriskNum` (the number of asterisks I need to use) and have it output the string of asterisks, not an integer of how many asterisks I need.

I definitely know I'm missing SOMETHING, but even after asking my teacher and scouring through my textbook and notes, I can't figure out how to solve this specific issue.

```
#include<iostream>

#include<iomanip>

#include<string>

#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
   string asterisk = "*";
   string firstName;
   int PopNum{0};
   int year{1900};
   int asteriskNum{};
   const string INTROLINE{"POPULATION GROWTH \n(each * represents 1000 people)"};
   cout << INTROLINE << "\n";

   string inFileName="DL8_L5_Morrison.txt";
   ifstream inFile{inFileName};

if (inFile){

   cout << inFileName << " opened for reading. \n";

   inFile >> firstName;

   while (not inFile.eof()){
     inFile >> PopNum;
     asteriskNum = PopNum/1000;
     cout << year << " " << asteriskNum << " " <<  << "\n";
     year+=20;

   inFile.close();
}
else {
   cout << inFileName << " did not open for reading. \n";}
   cout<<"Goodbye!\n";
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
}
```

Comment: I started to format your code but, while doing so, I noticed some issues with (seemingly) missing closing braces (`}`). Please check (thoroughly) and apply any required corrections. (Correcting code in other people's questions is a no-go thing here on Stack Overflow.)

Comment: Fix that formatting.... Curently the code is unreadable.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `std::string` object and use the constructor that takes a count and character as arguments ([constructor version #2 here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)). This *will* work with an `int` for the count argument, but it is *better* to cast it to a `size_t` type (or just have the calculated value as a `size_t` in the first place):

```cpp
//...
  asteriskNum = PopNum/1000;
  cout << year << " " << std::string(static_cast<size_t>(asteriskNum), '*') << std::endl;
//...
```

Comment: Using the string constructor is a good solution I wouldn't have considered.  However, I'm wondering what is your rationale for casting to size_t?

Comment: It is *worse* to use unnecessary casts.  A `static_cast` will force the compiler to shut up and accept a whole bunch of bad conversions.  Use explicit control over the type if you must, but do so with a plain implicit conversion and not a cast.

Comment: @Perette Without the *explicit* cast to a `size_t`, your compiler will likely issue a warning about an *implicit* conversion between the (signed) `int` given and the (unsigned) `size_t` expected. However, as Ben Voigt says, whether shutting up the compiler's warning in such a fashion is good or bad is a matter of debate.